# Convert DateTime (from SQL Live table) into DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a live SQL table in Excel which is ran every day (for previous day / weekend) and after this has ran the data is then transferred to a new tab.  The VBA  then converts the date-time to DD/MM/YYYY (see below example), however the problem I have it takes a long time to run due to the volume of data that is within the dataset.  Does anyone know of a quicker method to do this?

```
Dim rgCell As Range

 

   With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataTemplate")

      LastRowText = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

      .Range("A2:A" & LastRowText).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

      For Each rgCell In .Range("A2:A" & LastRowText).Cells

         If IsDate(rgCell.Value) Then rgCell.Value = CDate(rgCell.Value)

      Next rgCell

   End With
```

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do. You convert a value to a Date if it is already a Date?

Answer (score 0):

Use an array:

```
Dim arr() as variant, x as long

arr = .Range("A2:A" & LastRowText).value

for x = 1 to ubound(arr)
   If IsDate(arr(x, 1)) Then arr(x, 1) = CDate(arr(x, 1))
next x

SomeOtherSheet.Range("A1").resize(ubound(arr), 1) = arr
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already have date values, this is all that is needed:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataTemplate")
    LastRowText = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A2:A" & LastRowText).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"  
End With
```